# Export button in Highchart collapses with the Chart title using bootstrap in mobile - i have attached the screenshot

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

[image]Export button in Highchart collapses with the Chart title in bootstrap - i have attached the screenshot
I am using Bootstrap - for Export button i used the following code for export button.

I need to show this properly in mobile view

```
exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        symbol: 'url("/img/download-icon.png")',
                        text: 'Export'
                    }
                },
            }
```

Comment: Just tested with the default button. Works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/tssybksL/ - could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? We would be able to check this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please add the following code and check it. You have to resize yur browser to mobile view for viewing this:
$('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: "Test title for an overlapping exporting button"
        },
         exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        symbol: 'url(https://help.comodo.com/images/download-help.jpg)',
                        text: 'Export'
                    }
                },
            },

Comment: Indeed, looks like a bug to me. Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4231). Thanks!